# Send value of a field created in a workflow as an email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2007, sharepoint-email, workflow-lookup

I have a workflow which collects user input in regard to a hyperlink field. A second workflow then takes the value in this hyperlink field and copies it into the original list. Is it possible to send an email with the link provided in the hyperlink field in the task? I thought about using a lookup but I do not know what I need to fill in the fields of the lookup.

Comment: have you tried editing email content and inserting using Fx button

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!

In the email I created a lookup with the original list as source and the hyperlink field as the field. In the second part of the lookup window I took the ID field of the original list and as the value I took the current item and the id field.